# How to deal with an 8 year boy googling the word "sex"?

Tags: sex-education

My friend is in a dilemma, his has caught his 8 year boy googling the the words "beauty sex" , the child has grown in a very good environment and his parents are conservative, he even misspelt the word "beauty" as "beaty" because of his young age. 
He has two brothers and they have a very good behaviour
He has some sort of ADHD which will make my friends job even more difficult to talk to him.

Comment: Related: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/707/19428

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is nothing worrying about an 8 year old being interested in what sex is. And in the kind of world an 8 year old lines in, searching for an explanation on the internet is something that probably just came to his mind when he wanted to know more. Unless there's other indications (like sexually aggressive behavior) there is nothing wrong with an 8 year old being interested in the topic.

> Most children aged six to eight will: Look to peers, media, and other sources for information about sex

[Source](http://www.advocatesforyouth.org/publications/154-parents)

For comparison: at 8, I had already had basic sex education at school (in Germany). I knew anatomical terms, knew roughly what a period was (I am female, but all of this was taught to all students), knew sex was what causes pregnancy, the basics of pregnancy, and had seen schematic drawings of sex, including an erect penis.

The best thing your friend can do is talk to his son about sex in an age-appropriate way, answer his questions as best as she can (or find someone else to talk to him - maybe the other parent, if one is in his life), but also tell him that the internet is not the best place to look for information for sex. It is way too easy to accidentally be exposed to something she wouldn't want him exposed to like that. 
[This is a nice article](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/sexual-health/in-depth/sex-education/art-20046025) about sex education for school aged children, but there's a lot more websites and books out there. [This is a short article](http://www.aboutkidshealth.ca/En/HealthAZ/FamilyandPeerRelations/Sexuality/Pages/Sex-Education-Age-Appropriate-For-Children-what-they-should-learn-and-when.aspx) about what knowledge is often taught to children at what age

Comment: Good answer! This is indeed a pretty normal activity; it's the modern version of looking up _sex_ and other "naughty" words in the dictionary. (Unfortunately, the Internet can be MUCH more informative than the average dictionary.)

Comment: @Erica and more graphic ;-) although my books about sexuality as a child were quite explicit they weren't *that* explicit

Comment: Great answer. There is nothing wrong with a child's curiosity - this is a chance to engage in good, positive, education

Answer (score -10):

I would say that yes, you do have a very good concern. His googling "sex" will only escalate to other things- pornography (which will be seen if googling sex). Pornography is actually clinically addictive, and as  a male myself you have no idea how viewing- even a single time- really affects your whole thinking process. If I were you, I would get a great parental program. What I have on my computer (and it free, no I'm not soliciting) is k9 blue coat. it's free, and works great. I strongly recommend this for your older sons too.

Comment: Your solution only works on your computer, and so forces your children to look up these things where you're not able to watch. How do you handle them doing the same search on someone else's machine?

Comment: In fact the boy used an iPad

Comment: This sounds like it could be a useful party of a broader set of actions to take -- or do you really feel it's as simple as installing parental controls on the computer and moving on?

Comment: Googling "sex" does not necessarily mean that the kid is interested in or will discover pornography. It's possible - even probable - that he just wants to know more, which is not only normal, but very, *very* healthy! The appropriate response isn't to try to cut off a behavior that hasn't even begun to be a problem, but instead to talk to him and give him a healthy, frank understanding of sex.

Comment: @ creationEdge and erica: I love you guys! you are absolutely right! Controlling the exterior motives will never fix the problem that we all have: and that is our inherent sin problem. Only Jesus can fix that. but to stay on  topic... @Kevin do your homework bro. go google sex and open the first 15 links that show up and tell me if you don't find someone exposed or crudely dressed. Also, If I'm someone who has never heard of sex, and I read" its when a daddy puts his... in ..." don't you think I'm gonna google ... too?

Comment: @JeremyH, if a child needs to "google" these '...', the parents missed the right time to talk about sex in an age-apropriate and (in my opinion) positive and respectful way and encourage questions to be asked within the family circle.

Comment: @Stephie what are the benefits of learning about sex at an early age? I see very few pros, and many cons.

Comment: @JeremyH - you can influence and set the tone *before any uncontrollable "source of information" gives a wrong idea*. Children are naturally curious. If *we* supply the answers, we can choose how they are phrased and include our values and beliefs.

Comment: 1+ Very true, stephie. I suppose it is then up to the parents to decide how long they can wait before other people or information gets to them first. Which, can be quite a while. I know several individuals who didn't know what sex was for a long time. the one was 13, and the other(still doesn't even know what hot means) is 14(like i said, still doesn't know). Even then, the only info they got was from their parents. I suppose the method of schooling (public or home-schooled) is a major factor in whether or not to tell your child at the ripe old age of 8. These kids were homeschooled.